# Avast android anti-virus detected "Android:Looter-Z" [PUP], in my app

Tags: android

I have this app "[Networking Cables](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alamopcmatix.networkingcables&hl=en)",
someone sent to me email, he say:
"Avast android anti-virus detected "Android:Looter-Z" [PUP]"
in my app,

when I check my app No virus.

What does this mean?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking this [post from Avast](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=147262.msg1069208#msg1069208). It appears that there was an issue in their detection with whatever definitions your user is using. They recommend just updating your definitions and trying again. I would suggest this to your user.